# getting error like xxx is not declared.it may not access due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net, gridview

using vb.net .bind dataset value to gridview. and send this gridview to outlook using smtpclient in vb.net. able to bind the data in gridview control.  it shows error like above in the code when i call the sendmail function.

GridView designing code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdv2" runat ="server" width="100%" autogeneratedcolumn="false">
 <columns>
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="TRREQNO" DataField="TRREQNO" ItemStyle-Width="50"/>
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="From" DataField="ename" ItemStyle-Width="50"/>
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Departure Date" DataField="departuredate" ItemStyle-Width="50"/>
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Return Date" DataField="returndate" ItemStyle-Width="50"/>
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Passport" DataField="havepassport" ItemStyle-Width="50"/>
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Passport Number" DataField="passportnumber" ItemStyle-Width="50"/>
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Travel Type" DataField="traveltype" ItemStyle-Width="50"/>
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Additional Passengers" DataField="noofcopassenger" ItemStyle-Width="50"/>
 </columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Code behind file .aspx.vb

```
 Dim ds_get As New TR_REQTableAdapters.proc_bindingridTableAdapter
 Dim dt_get As TR_REQ.proc_bindingridDataTable = ds_get.GetData(s1)
 gdv2.datasource = dt_get
 gdv2.databind()

  SendHTMLMail()

Public Sub SendHTMLMail()
    Dim Msg As New MailMessage()
    Dim fromMail As New MailAddress("xxx")
    ' Sender e-mail address.
    Msg.From = fromMail
    ' Recipient e-mail address.
    Msg.[To].Add(New MailAddress("xxx"))
    ' Subject of e-mail
    Msg.Subject = "Send Gridivew in EMail"
    Msg.Body += "Please check below data <br/><br/>"
    Msg.Body += GetGridviewData(gdv2)
    Msg.IsBodyHtml = True
    Dim sSmtpServer As String = ""
    sSmtpServer = "10.200.4.59"
    Dim a As New SmtpClient()
    a.Host = sSmtpServer
    a.EnableSsl = True
    a.Send(Msg)
End Sub

Public Function GetGridviewData(ByVal gv As GridView) As String
    Dim strBuilder As New StringBuilder()
    Dim strWriter As New StringWriter(strBuilder)
    Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(strWriter)
    gv.RenderControl(htw)
    Return strBuilder.ToString()
End Function
```

Last function in line 4 am getting the error mentioned in the above. How to solve?

Comment: Is the `GridView` variable `gdv2` declared in the designer codebehind file? If not, rename it on the aspx, save, rename back to `gdv2`, save.

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter gdv2 is declared in the designer codebehind file

Comment: Don't shorten error messages. You should show us them at least in the question itself. So don't obfuscate it with `"getting error like xxx"`. Where are the first lines of your code located, in `Page_Load` or where?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter first part of the code in button clik

Comment: getting error gdv2 is not declared.it may not access due to its protection level

Comment: @Tim Schmelter i changed mycode ,even am getting error

Comment: Can you post the portion of the designer file (`aspx.designer.vb`) where the gridview `gdv2` is declared?

Comment: @vps: you should have 3 files - `.aspx`, `.aspx.designer.vb` and `.aspx.vb`.  The designer file is where the declarative controls you add to the aspx are instantiated.  The designer is auto-generated when the aspx changes (hence Tim's initial suggestion).